# How to add custom content in child template in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a `index.html.twig` page as my homepage with extend 
`{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}` 
pointing to `app/Resources/Views` base template and my that base template extends a 
`{% extends "UAMBootstrapBundle::stickyfooter.html.twig" %}`

How I can add some custom content to get displayed on my homepage template  `index.html.twig`? Whenever I add contents the error is that I can't any body to it if it has extends.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message you're getting instead of just a synopsis of it.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error if forget to use the {% block %}{% endblock %}

So you need to create a block in you base.html.twig which you can 'fill' in your index.html.twig

Example in base.html.twig

```
 {% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

In your index.html.twig

```
 {% block %}My content{% endblock %}
```